# Chaincode instantiation failing with other go packages

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

need help on chaincode instantiation which is dependent on other go packages like golang/protobuf and pkg/errors. Below is the error i am getting in the peer logs,

```
2018-01-10 19:59:42.040 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 405 failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc"  on transaction 380f014688cb8638b66cc9e9c8c85f1bf06ba062fbb979442483f7e9ae2139be, error: Error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "chaincode/input/src/Loyalty/loyalty.go:15:2: cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto" in any of:
  /opt/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOROOT)
  /chaincode/input/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOPATH)
  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
chaincode/input/src/Loyalty/loyalty.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/pkg/errors" in any of:
  /opt/go/src/github.com/pkg/errors (from $GOROOT)
  /chaincode/input/src/github.com/pkg/errors (from $GOPATH)
  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/pkg/errors
```

I've already mounted these to the peer docker and are present at these `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` locations

Comment: Based on the error it's not only expecting the proto package but proto package in a specific location. Does your GOPATH work correctly? You could just ran go install ./... to make sure proto binary is in pkg to get rid of the error if path is configured.

Comment: Hi, Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile chaincode the peer starts new container using `fabric-ccenv` base image. As a result mounted to the peer folder `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` is not available at runtime.

It's better to vendor the `proto` package with the chaincode, try to run following command in the root folder of your project:

```
govendor add github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
```

This command should create subfolder `vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` and populate it with all necessary files. 
Just try to install your chaincode again, required dependencies will be shipped  with your source code and are availalbe in runtime.